# Ui router - nested view with modal box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am trying to show a modal box based on the url using Angular ui.
I have three states - home, setting, and modal based on the setting state.

```
$stateProvider
   .state('home',{
        url:'/',
      views: {
            'content': {
               templateUrl: 'views/partials/content.html',
               controller: 'ContentCtrl'
            }
      })
   .state('home.setting',{
         url:'/setting',
       views:{
           'content@': {
                  templateUrl: '/views/partials/setting.html',
                  controller: 'SettingCtrl'
           }
      })
   .state('home.setting.modal',{
       url:'^/modal',
      onEnter: function($state, $modal, $timeout, $stateParams, $location) {
           if ($stateParams.id === "") {
                return $location.path('/');
           } else {
                $modal.open({
                      templateUrl: 'views/modals/deepResultModal.html',
                      controller: "DeepResultCtrl",

                }).result.then(function() {

                 }, function() {
                     return $location.path('/');
                });
           }
      }   
}
```

With this code, I keep getting this

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr? p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%….setting.modal'%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fve...<omitted>...e)
```

I tried "home.modal" state instead of "home.setting.modal", but it removes the parent state.

How can I show a modal box without removing a parent state? I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231608/angular-ui-router-modal-removes-parent-state) and I nested the states like "home.setting.modal" but it doesn't work.

It would be great if you can help me out! Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is an extra comma after $location in the onEnter. Was that a copy paste error or is it really like that?  Also, have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr  It sounds like you might be missing a module.

Comment: You are also missing a single quotation here: `.state('home.setting.modal,{` should be `.state('home.setting.modal',{`

Comment: I am sorry. I made those mistakes when I was pasting the source code. I checked the link but it didn't solve my problem.